# Mysql sum using a group by on one field while also considering another field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a joined table from which I want to sum the attribute amounts and also group by name.

```
joined_tb
name        attr        amount
billy       'attr1'     2
billy       'attr2'     4
billy       'attr1'     7
billy       'attr3'     8
jean        'attr2'     6
jean        'attr1'     1
jean        'attr2'     11
```

This table is a result of a join between these two tables using `id`

```
t1                  t2
id  name            id    attr      amount
1   billy           1     'attr1'   2
2   jean            1     'attr2'   4
                    1     'attr1'   7
                    1     'attr3'   8
                    2     'attr2'   6
                    2     'attr1'   1
                    2     'attr2'   11
```

I want to end up with this table:

```
result_tb
name        attr        amount
billy       'attr1'     9
billy       'attr2'     4
billy       'attr3'     8
jean        'attr1'     1
jean        'attr2'     17
```

I am able to sum by `attr`, but it ignores `name`. How can I get `result_tb` from `t1` and `t2`?

Comment: Use group by for group of columns: attr,name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t1.name, t2.attr, sum(t2.amount) from t1
join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.name, t2.attr
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Below:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.attr, sum(t2.amount) as totalamount
FROM table1 as t1 LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.name, t2.attr
```